# How to calculate J meter individual response time in load test for a set of requests

Tags: testing, time, jmeter, load, response

Response time is calculated by adding max time for each request

Test 1: For 1 user the max response time for the requests are 24 seconds 
Test 2: For 25 users it is 92 seconds

now in 2nd test what is the individual user response time?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in individual users response times you can add [__threadNum()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__threadNum) function as a prefix (or postfix) of your request. This way JMeter will generate an individual Sample Result for each and every thread (virtual user)

[image: JMeter ThreadNum]

You can also get response times plotted via [Response Times Over Time](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ResponseTimesOverTime/) listener. The listener can be installed using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager)

[image: JMeter Plugins Manager - Response Times Over Time]

If you combine these 2 approaches you will get individual response times on your test timeline

[image: JMeter Response Times Over Time]